# enabled services in devstack

Tags: openstack, devstack

I installed devstack and it seems working fine.
But when focusing on the dashboard precisely in the project tab I don't have neither the "Manage Network" Section nor the "Object Store" Section.
I noticed this after comparing with the trystack sandbox.
Is that normal?

Answer (score 2):

The list of enabled services in devstack is configured using the localrc file. The neutron network service and the Swift storage service are off by default. 
The following modifications should enable both:

```
disable_service n-net
enable_service q-svc
enable_service q-agt
enable_service q-dhcp
enable_service q-l3
enable_service q-meta
enable_service neutron 

enable_service swift
```

Answer (score 0):

Devstack docs say put the following in local.conf:

`enable_service s-proxy s-object s-container s-account`

Answer (score 0):

The list of enabled services in devstack is configured in local.conf file.

When you need to enable object storage (swift) with Devstack, you need to put below lines into your local.conf file:

```
# Enable swift services
enable_service s-proxy
enable_service s-object
enable_service s-container
enable_service s-account

# Enable tempurls and set credentials
SWIFT_HASH=your_hash ("abc123" for example :D)
SWIFT_TEMPURL_KEY=your_key ("abc123" for example :D)
SWIFT_ENABLE_TEMPURLS=True
```